Difficulty at engine start with clicking noises, after battery service
It's an old car, and I just had a local mechanical shop serviced the car, including its battery.
After the service, I started noticing difficulties at engine start, with clicking noises. I can reliably reproduce this symptom, and to avoid the issue, I have to use force and turn the key very hard to the end to start the engine. Previously, I never had to use so much force to turn the key.
Please let me know if you need more information, and I highly appreciate any hints and suggestions.

What else was involved with the service that was performed?

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

I had to open the hood myself, and discovered red oil sprayed all over the place on the "+" and "-" terminals. A large part of the oil got into the metal contact surface, and I think it affected the electricity connection. I removed the oil by paper towel, and the issue disappeared. So far, so good. I will update again if it comes back again.
